# Obtener primer,segundo y tercer lugar de una tabla MYSQL,JSP JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Buen dia.
estoy teniendo incoveniente al obtener el equipo en primera,segunda y tercera posicion mas su puntaje,la data es obtenida de una tabla llamada score en mysql y se muestra en pagina.jsp,adjunta imagenes.
[image: Tabla Posiciones]

Ahora cuando ejecuto la siguiente la siguiente funcion no me arroja el resultado adecuado.
[image: resultado]

```
function calculartp(){       

            var pts = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='PTS']");
            var equipo = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='Equipo']");
            var arreglo= [];

            for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
                arreglo.push({"equipo":equipo[i].innerHTML,"pts":pts[i].innerHTML});
            }


            arreglo.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.pts < b.pts) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (a.pts > b.pts) {
                    return -1;
                }

                return 0;
            });


                contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts + '\n';
                contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[1].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[1].pts + '\n';
                contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[2].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[2].pts + '\n';
                alert(contenido);


   }
```

espero su gentil apoyo.

Comment: Intenta seleccionando de esta forma `[data-title='Equipo']`;

Comment: estuve realizando algunos cambios y ya encontre la solucion. tuve que modificar en esta parte:   // Salida / construccion de contenido
                    contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[3].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[3].pts + '\n';
                    contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[6].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[6].pts + '\n';
                    alert(contenido);